# Nano unresponsive when using git commit - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: git, nano

Can anyone provide some assistance with Nano? When I do a git commit -a -m "blah some text" it brings up the Nano editor, but the editor is completely unresponsive to my keyboard commands including any ctrl+ menu commands?

I end up having to close the terminal window...am stuck atm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you git commit it brings up a [VIM editor](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_06_02.html) not nano. VIM is a really powerful text editor but it has loads of commands to let you quickly insert text and move around the document. However to type you must press <kbd>i</kbd> and then type and press <kbd>ESC</kbd> when done.

You can remove the `-a` to take it out of interactive mode so it just uses your original message.

Comment: No idea, this from a fresh install, I don't think I have VIM installed yet. I don't get it, using -m "..." should by-pass using an editor altogether if I mistaken? The frozen nano is puzzling...end up having to just close the terminal window.

Comment: VIM is built into GIT (I think). `-m` by-passes the editor all together, but `-a` forces the editor to appear anyway. Remove `-a` and your commit will go through straight away. If you want interactive mode I think you are forced to use VIM. Try pressing <kbd>i</kbd> then typing, this will tell you if it is VIM.

Comment: I've tried it without -a... Initially I get this message below, and when I repeat the command it brings up the unresponsive nano. --- user@user-Ubuntu:/var/www/projects/crud_mvc_oop$ gksu git commit -m "1st commit"
error: There was a problem with the editor 'editor'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: Why are you using `gksu` for your commit? If you don't have rights to edit files then use `sudo` not `gksu` that is for graphical programs. You are sure it is nano? You have tried <kbd>i</kbd> then typing to see if it is VIM?

Comment: Looks like using sudo working. (sudo git commit -m "text") What are the differences with gksu and sudo? New to Ubuntu. The reason I used gksu was because I didn't better way to do it without having permissions. Is there an easy way to grant permissions to the login user?

Comment: The difference between `gksu` and `sudo` is subtle. The main point they set certain environment variables differently, becuase `sudo` expects you to run a command line program and `gksu` a graphical one. You can't give yourself permissions (well you could but it is a really bad idea) because linux purposefully separates root and user privileges for security.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown explanation of sudo and gksu, very helpful! So do you recommend continuing to just using sudo instead of granting privileges?

Comment: Yeah use `sudo`.